# Tokenization of text file in python 3.5

Tags: python

I'm trying to do tokenization of words in a text file using python 3.5 but have a couple of errors. Here is the code:

```
import re
f = open('/Users/Half_Pint_Boy/Desktop/sentenses.txt', 'r')
a=0
c=0
for line in f:
    b=re.split('[^a-z]', line.lower()) 
    a+=len(filter(None, b))
    c = c + 1
    d = d + b
print (a)
print (c)
```

My questions:

1. Construction `a+=len(filter(None, b))` works fine in python 2.7 but in 3.5 it cause an error of type that object of:

   > type 'filter' has no `len()`

   How can it be solved using python 3.5?
2. When I'm doing tokenization, my code counts also empty spaces as word-tokens. How can I delete them?

Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the first point! but how exactly can I get rid of the empty tokens completely after splitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need an explicit cast to list in Python 3.5 to get the length of your sequence, as `filter` returns an *iterator* object and not a list as with Python 2.7:

   ```
   a += len(list(filter(None, b)))
   #         ^^
   ```
2. The empty spaces where returned from your `re.split`, e.g.:

   ```
   >>> line  = 'sdksljd sdjsh 1213hjs sjdks'
   >>> b=re.split('[^a-z]', line.lower())
   >>> b
   ['sdksljd', 'sdjsh', '', '', '', '', 'hjs', 'sjdks']
   ```

---

You can remove them using a filter on `if` in a *list comprehension* on the results from your `re.split` like so:

```
b = [i for i in re.split('[^a-z]', line.lower()) if i]
```

The `if i` part in the list comp. returns `False` for an empty string because `bool('') is False`. So empty strings are cleared.

---

The results from the list comprehension can also be achieved with `filter` (which you already used with `a`):

```
b = list(filter(None, re.split('[^a-z]', line.lower()))) # use the list comprehension if you don't like brackets
```

---

And finally, `a` can be computed after any of the two approaches as:

```
a += len(b)
```

Comment: Do you know why OP filters on `None`? Did he expect the empty strings would disappear?

Comment: @RadLexus The filter on `None` does remove blanks, but I have a feeling they are still using the original `b` somewhere with `d = d + b`